# Assets precompiled in server but not showing with puma and nginx server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, puma

I successfully deployed rails app using Capistrano with puma and ngnix. After deploy, assets are not loading in the server. I am able to do assets precompile in the server using this command: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets: precompile and locally both. I am able to see precompiled assets in public folder. Locally it is working fine. but it is not loading assets in server. I am unable to fix it.

Production.rb

```
    "Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
#  config.serve_static_assets =true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
 # config.assets.precompile += ['omnisling.scss']

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  #config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  #
  # Created new env variable in server .bashrc file as ENV["EMAIL_HOST"] to hold the domain name
  # And Changed below line with new env variable, ref: https://omnisling.atlassian.net/browse/OMNS-54
  # Changed By: Aravind Sankar
  # Date : 25 June 2018

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => ENV["EMAIL_HOST"]}

  config.after_initialize do
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
    # ::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::JetpayGateway.new(
    #     # :login     => 'TESTMCC3016X',
    #     :login     => 'AO03B5GME9ZK',
    #     version:    {subscriber: 'BOZHZU', dll: 'GreenBasket 1.0'}
    # )

    # paypal_options = {
    #   login: ENV['PAYPAL_LOGIN'],
    #   password: ENV['PAYPAL_PASSWORD'],
    #   signature: ENV['PAYPAL_SECRET']
    # }
    # ::EXPRESS_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_options)

    # spreedly_options = {
    #   login:  ENV['SPREEDLY_ENV_KEY'],
    #   password: ENV['SPREEDLY_ACCESS_SECRET'],
    #   gateway_token: ENV['SPREEDLY_GATEWAY_KEY']
    # }
    # ::SPREEDLY_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::SpreedlyCoreGateway.new(spreedly_options)
  end

  # Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({
  #   :storage => :s3,
  #   :bucket => ENV["S3_BUCKET"],
  #   :path           => ':class/:id/:style.:extension',
  #   :s3_credentials => {
  #     :access_key_id => ENV["S3_SECRET"],
  #     :secret_access_key => ENV["S3_ACCESS_KEY"]
  #   },
  #   :s3_protocol => :https,
  #   :s3_headers => { 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000', 'Expires' => 10.years.from_now.httpdate }
  # })

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
          :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
          :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
          :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      },
      :url => ':s3_domain_url',
      :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
  }

  # Commented to test AWS SES. Below is for Sendgrid.
  # config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  #  :address              => ENV['SMTP_ADDRESS'],
  #  :port                 => ENV['SMTP_PORT'],
  #  :user_name            => ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'],
  #  :password             => ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
  #  :authentication       => 'plain',
  #  :enable_starttls_auto => true
  # }

  # For AWS SES
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => ENV['SES_SMTP_ADDRESS'],
      :port => ENV['SES_SMTP_PORT'],
      :user_name => ENV['SES_SMTP_USERNAME'],
      :password => ENV['SES_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
      :authentication => :login,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"

  # Rails.application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
  #  :email => {
  #    :email_prefix => ENV["ERROR_PREFIX"],
  #    :sender_address => ENV["ERROR_SENDERS"],
  #    :exception_recipients => ENV["RECEIVERS"].split(", ")
  #  }

  #
  # Created new env variable in server .bashrc file as ENV["EMAIL_HOST"] to hold the domain name
  # And Changed below line with new env variable, ref: https://omnisling.atlassian.net/browse/OMNS-54
  # Changed By: Aravind Sankar
  # Date : 25 June 2018
  #
  #config.action_controller.asset_host = ENV["HOST"]
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = ENV["EMAIL_HOST"]
end"
```

ngnix.conf

```
" # For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
#include /usr/local/nginx/conf/mime.types;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    client_max_body_size 80M;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#        root /home/deploy/omnisling/public;
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }

#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}"
```

var/log/nginx/error.log

```
"2018/12/06 01:16:16 [error] 28064#0: *4 open() "/home/deploy/omnisling/develop/public/assets/os/pos-054e3367b9d18905b322b96613e13dd71c0721a5a1d647b5e8518909c38c288b.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 106.51.74.45, server: localhost, request: "GET /assets/os/pos-054e3367b9d18905b322b96613e13dd71c0721a5a1d647b5e8518909c38c288b.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "52.86.42.50", referrer: "http://52.86.42.50/"
2018/12/06 01:16:16 [error] 28064#0: *1 open() "/home/deploy/omnisling/develop/public/assets/os/ecommerce-ef0801aee6a3ded0a641d7626c7e34a51492f35e3b3e40c42b480f57c8e58917.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 106.51.74.45, server: localhost, request: "GET /assets/os/ecommerce-ef0801aee6a3ded0a641d7626c7e34a51492f35e3b3e40c42b480f57c8e58917.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "52.86.42.50", referrer: "http://52.86.42.50/"
2018/12/06 01:16:16 [error] 28064#0: *5 open() "/home/deploy/omnisling/develop/public/assets/os/mobile_apps-9ec5e2983b86b63469a8b5e41ba287dac94b62e615098973417c24eb34783bfe.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 106.51.74.45, server: localhost, request: "GET /assets/os/mobile_apps-9ec5e2983b86b63469a8b5e41ba287dac94b62e615098973417c24eb34783bfe.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "52.86.42.50", referrer: "http://52.86.42.50/"
2018/12/06 01:16:16 [error] 28064#0: *3 open() "/home/deploy/omnisling/develop/public/assets/os/cart-icon-7b627cb7122f2bdb354ff0caf1d4fe060a2bb26f6e35f73fd945d71d1115201e.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 106.51.74.45, server: localhost, request: "GET /assets/os/cart-icon-7b627cb7122f2bdb354ff0caf1d4fe060a2bb26f6e35f73fd945d71d1115201e.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "52.86.42.50", referrer: "http://52.86.42.50/"
2018/12/06 01:16:16 [error] 28064#0: *6 open() "/home/deploy/omnisling/develop/public/assets/os/pos_icon-7669c3f57465dbe3533a2ff738a867a04e31bf57aa0500d37897025921043c7b.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 106.51.74.45, server: localhost, request: "GET /assets/os/pos_icon-7669c3f57465dbe3533a2ff738a867a04e31bf57aa0500d37897025921043c7b.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "52.86.42.50", referrer: "http://52.86.42.50/"
2018/12/06 01:16:16 [error] 28064#0: *7 open() "/home/deploy/omnisling/develop/public/assets/os/mobile_apps_icon-c763792f0bcdf4d9332a1f72d163d7851df70dfcb8ba868e614773b3c30a2978.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 106.51.74.45, server: localhost, request: "GET /assets/os/mobile_apps_icon-c763792f0bcdf4d9332a1f72d163d7851df70dfcb8ba868e614773b3c30a2978.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "52.86.42.50", referrer: "http://52.86.42.50/"
"
```

[image]
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to set :  config.asset.compile = false

Comment: Afterwards it is expected that the files will be precompiled somewhere

Comment: i tried  config.asset.compile = false but didn't work

Comment: do the files exist on the server that those paths? does the nginx process have read permissions for those files?

Comment: All the files exist in public/assets folder in server. Nginx process has read permission for those files.

Comment: Where is the static file routing in the `nginx.conf`? .... A biased debugging tip / question: does it work when using the iodine with the static file service enabled (`iodine -www ./public` from the command line)? If so, it's an nginx configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

Share what you have on your production public asset folder.. look for sprockets manifest file. Look for assets that are precompiled to ensure the compilation is happening as programmed.

something like this
.sprockets-manifest-ffff2c8e85485d1908eaad36e244e93d.json

Comment: I have shared my public/assets folder which is in the server. But as you said I am not able to see any .sprockets-manifest2515ea798d82da69c042f1584ceb6a6e.json file in server. But I am able to see that file in locally. Can u please review this?

Answer (score 0):

This should enable:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

But faced then with "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" related issue when JavaScript marked "html".

And actual Rails have this:

```
config.public_file_server.enabled
```

Then all works fine. And no "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" error.